# Android Studio Team Project

Tags: android-studio, version-control, azure-devops, collaboration

I would like to ask if it is possible in AS where my team members can work in different computer on a same shared project. where we can check in for changes made in project and get latest version. Just like Visual Studio Team Explorer/Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Git with VSTS?

Comment: in VS i used TFS.. but for android I have no idea how to work in a team where we can edit the coding and sync with other computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). It free and help you manage project easily. You can separate project to many milestones, log and tracking issues...

Comment: i have a gitHub account, but can my team member what i upload and save changes to my github?

Comment: Assuming I am doing VCS now creating a git repository by using github account, how can I share my repo to my team members, and how can they commit changes to the repo?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/ Check this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use VSO Git Repository and [Visual Studio Team Foundation Plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/10/23/team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-idea.aspx) in AS.